# Regex parse string in python

Tags: python, regex

I have various strings. I want to check if a string is firstly in the format of `xy:someword` and then retrieve the `someword` part. `xy` should be characters from a to z.

For example:

`eu:road` should give me `road`

`somestring 100` should give me `None`

`road:eu` should give me `None`

How can I implement this ?

Comment: use pattern `'\w\w:\w+'`. Please note that you should really try to implement it yourself BEFORE going on SO then if you cannot succeed, show what you have tried and ask.

Comment: replace `^[a-z]{2}:|.*` by empty string

Comment: Do you need to use regex?  Couldn't you split on the `:` and return the second half if the first half is only 2 chars?

Comment: You don't need regex. Just check for index of ":" Return everything after

Comment: @FirebladeDan That doesn't guarantee that before `:` I have characters from a to z

Comment: If four characters before the colon mean the string doesn't pass, splitting on the colon or finding its index aren't enough.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 sure it is. Just make sure the colon is at the same index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regex like `^[a-z]{2}:(\w+)$` and then use `group(1)` to get the content of the capturing group (`(...)`):

```
>>> p = "^[a-z]{2}:(\w+)$"
>>> re.match(p, "eu:road").group(1)
'road'
>>> re.match(p, "road:eu")
None
```

Comment: Why does `print re.search('\w\w:(\w+)', 'road:eu').group(1)` print `eu` ?

Comment: @Shiro because you miss the anchor `^`

Comment: Ok. `^` is the beginning and `$` is the ending of the string ?

Comment: @Shiro Exactly. You have to use either `match` or use the anchor character `^` for "beginning of string. If you just use `search`, it will find any match within the string. Same for `$`: Without that, the string could extend after the match.